# Flickering when I log in even though I have the same wallpaper before and after logging in

Tags: greeter, wallpaper

If I use the same wallpaper on my desktop and on the greeter, there is a little flickering when log in.

Is there any way to integrate a greeter on Pantheon or Gala or something, that makes this transition more fluid or even makes it disappear?

I have no idea whether it is feasible or possible or even if it happens due to my graphics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it is because login screen (greeter) and the desktop environment are a bit different entities. Lightdm starts the greeter, but desktop is handled by another entity, pantheon. They use same image only because system configures both at the same time when you change it.

Comment: This is indeed the expected, although undesirable, behaviour.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. In principle, since the X server remains active, the background never needs to change. In practice, making the transition seamless would be pretty complex given all that happens when a GUI session starts.

Comment: @Gilles the question was "why?", not "how can we make it so it doesn't". It might be worth submitting a bug/blueprint to launchpad, but it doesn't seem like there is a certain immediate solution to this. And it's barely worth wasting time on it.

Comment: Thanks V_Pavel . Anyway as I said in the description it could be possible to link greeter and pantheon, no? Lightdm call one and both wake, if the same wallpaper is used then transition is more fluid. Theorically is possible no? I don't say it's easy or difficult, only ask if is possible

Comment: @ponytojas Technically possible, but that is not exactly the right place to discuss it :) You should submit a bug on Pantheon Launchpad (request "smooth" transition) - that would be more appropriate place to do it.